# Firefox seems to ignore padding on ::after element parent

Tags: css, firefox

I want to position a down arrow as an `::after` element. It works fine in any browser I tested, except in Firefox.

This is what it looks like in Firefox:
[image]

This is what it looks like in Chrome, Opera and Edge:
[image]

```css
.heading-wrapper {
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left: 6rem;
    }
    
    .menu__dropdown-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1rem;
    }

    .dropdown::after {
      content: "▼";
      font-size: 2rem;
      position: absolute;
      right: -1rem;
      bottom: -0.3rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="heading-wrapper menu__dropdown-wrapper">
         <h1 class="dropdown">
            <span class="first-letter heading-medium">Studio</span>
            <span class="first-letter heading-medium"></span>
         </h1>
    
    <div class="menu__dropdown-content">
     // menu items here
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems to be ignoring the padding. Does anyone know why or what I could do instead? I've been trying different combinations of `padding`, `margin`, `top`, `bottom` and `right` distances, but the result is always that the arrow in Firefox is incorrectly positioned.

**EDIT:**

I noticed that when I resize the viewport in Firefox so that the `font-size` and `paddings` change due to `Media Queries`, `paddings` are suddenly recognized - even on the full width example I posted above. But when I reload the page, `paddings` are gone again.

**EDIT 2:**

This is not specific to my browser either, as it appears on Firefox mobile as well as Firefoxes on other machines.

When I hover over the elements while having the dev tools open, `paddings` or `margins` show. But the arrow (or more words if there's more than one, e.g. `Studio Photos` just glues together in Firefox as `StudioGallery`.

**EDIT 3:**

So this seems to make Firefox recognize the padding:

```
 .dropdown {
  display: inline-flex; <-- now paddings get recognized
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Unfortunately it removes the formatting of the first letter. But that's better than not having spaces between words or the arrow in the totally wrong place...

Still, if anyone has an idea what the problem could be, I would appreciate it! This still seems very weird to me.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Firefox version < 3.6 then `::` for pseudo-class won't support rather try `:` which is supported almost all browser

Comment: Firefox version is 80.0b7. I still tried using `:` but it doesn't work either.